# Split 1 long excel column into several column based on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, formula, multiple-columns

In excel, how do you split 1 long column into several columns based on its value?

Assume in a column, we have:
[image]

The expected end-product is:
[image]

Can anyone please help? I tried looking on the internet, and features like "Text to columns" and "=INDEX" don't happen to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a specific formula/method to do what you're trying to do in a single method. You would have to do a combination of formulas or some pivot/power approaches. Assuming you have Excel's Spill Range functionality, the closest solution would be to put some filtered columns based on the value in the first column. I mocked up an example in this [file here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4QOUbUNABHlDQXxlg?e=4kUhD5). If you had hundreds of columns, this wouldn't be realistic and you'd have to consider using Index to drive your columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried your mocked-up example, and it works great. Unfortunately, my data is too big to be copied into Excel 365 (2 columns with 84092 rows), and it seems like it won't work in regular excel because of the Spill Range functionality. Do you have any references for how I should use the "=INDEX" function to work with it?

Comment: Index would just be an expansion of your spill range to make it dynamic. Too long to explain in a SO post. Glad it helped.